# Retrieve more than 1 mysql column using AND statement

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql and what I am tryng to achieve, is to select more than 1 column in a select statement. From the sample code I have posted, I can retrieve the value 'Box Retrieval' in the activity column. However, what I would like to do, is select the values, 'Box Retrieval' 'Box Return, etc, Is this possible. Thanks

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM act WHERE company = '".$_SESSION['kt_idcode_usr']."' AND activity = 'Box Retrieval' ORDER BY date DESC";
```

Comment: Can you provide here expected output ?

Comment: In the column activity, there are several values which I need to display. Box Return, Box Retrieval, Box Destruction. Thanks

Comment: can you plz explain more info

Comment: If you want to get all values of that column, don't restrict it in the `WHERE` clause to just a specific value.

Comment: Could you show example please. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 have you try below query friend ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this might be helpful for you.

`$query = "SELECT * FROM act WHERE activity IN ('Box Return', 'Box Retrieval', 'Box Destruction') AND company = '".$_SESSION['kt_idcode_usr']."' ORDER BY date DESC";`

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another condition with `OR` statement having the value you need -

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM act WHERE company = '".$_SESSION['kt_idcode_usr']."' AND activity = 'Box Retrieval' OR activity = 'Box Return' ORDER BY date DESC";
```

This will return all rows which have activity value either 'Box Retrieval' or 'Box Return'
You can repeat for more such cases.

Or you can use `UNION` of two SQL `SELECT` statements but I think `OR` should suffice in this case.